# How to show shapes at plot points with JFreeChart TimeSeries chart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart v1.0.19 to create the following time series chart:

[image]

...using the following code:

```
final String chartTitle = "";
final XYDataset dataset = createDataset1();

final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
    chartTitle, "Year End", "Turnover", dataset, true, false, false);

final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
final NumberAxis axis2 = new NumberAxis("Cash");
axis2.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);
plot.setDataset(1, createDataset2());
plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

final StandardXYItemRenderer renderer1 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
renderer1.setSeriesShape(0, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(5));
renderer1.setSeriesShapesFilled(0, true);
plot.setRenderer(0, renderer1);

final StandardXYItemRenderer renderer2 = new StandardXYItemRenderer();
renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.black);
renderer2.setSeriesShape(0, ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(5));
renderer2.setSeriesShapesFilled(0, true);
plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);

chart.getPlot().setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
chart.getXYPlot().setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
chart.getXYPlot().setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

...but I can't get the data points to show shapes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my renderer that was the problem. Changing from `StandardXYItemRenderer` to `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` e.g.

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true,true);
```

...did the trick. The two boolean args in the constructor are for switching on/off lines and shapes, respectively.